# Default folder permission created by composer install command

Tags: linux, symfony, permissions, composer-php

on Ubuntu (22.04) in my PHP application I run command *composer install* to download all depencies. It creates folder *vendor* with all downloaded dependencies.
This *vendor* folder is created with permission: ***drwxr-xr-x*** thats means write permission for owner but not for same group.

Please, is it possible to set write permisson also for group by default like  ***drwxrwxr-x*** (775)?

I have more servers and on one server is directory *vendor* created with write permission for group but on otherone without write permission. I don't know what setting could be different between these servers.

Comment: I'd expect this to be dependent on your `umask`, just like when you do `mkdir` by hand. So use `umask 002` before `composer install`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you. umask seems to be the solution (set default umask 0002 to ~/.bash_profile)

Comment: That's probably not something you want to do in your `.bash_profile`. This will make all files and folders you create group-writable. You should only do it before `composer install`, and undo it when you're done.

Comment: Thank you for your notice I understand but in my specific case is this global setting ok.

Comment: Are you facing any **specific** problem with these permissions? Are you sure that this is a problem directly related to Symfony itself?

Comment: @NicoHaase its not related to Symfony application I just wanted to intruduce what a where I do. Its related to OS. I can remove this word.

Answer (score 0):

The composer doesn’t has this functionality. You can run it with chmod simultaneously:

```
composer update && chmod -R 775 vendor
```

Or make own .sh script for updating composer dependencies.